# Horizontal align jpg icon in block title

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, block

I am new to beamer. I need to put an icon in the block environment title on the right side. 
My code looks like this :

```
\begin{exampleblock}
    { 
     \includegraphics[width=10pt]{frog.jpg} Example
    }
```

and my block then looks like this :

[image: Example Title]

I need the image to be on the right side (not the left).

I tried using`\includegraphics[width=10pt,left]` but got an error :

Package xkeyval Error: 'left' undefined in families 'Gin'.

I also tried `\begin{flushright} \includegraphics[.. \end{flushright}` and I got

[image: Example 2]

As you can see there is some kind of margin that I am unable to get rid of. I need it to be on the same line.

Comment: Do the `\begin{exampleblock} Example\hfill\includegraphics[width=10pt]{frog.jpg} \end{examplebox}` help?

Comment: L l ll rll pm I l l lot u l l nmy p o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
\begin{exampleblock} 
    Example
\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=10pt]{frog.jpg} 
\end{examplebox}
```